# GeoMedia WebMap with WFS 1.1.0 Filter Examples?

Tags: wfs, filter, geomedia

I'm having problems forming a GET query for WebMap spatial data using WFS 1.1.0.  My query looks like this:

```
http://USGVDCALIX2/WFS/Request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=500&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><BBOX><PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName><Box srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326"><lowerCorner>-72.742129821777 43.944567565918</lowerCorner><upperCorner>72.545288391113 44.148836975098</upperCorner></Envelope></Box></BBOX></Filter>&TYPENAME=Counties
```

But the result is:

```
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.1.0"><Exception exceptionCode="GWMWFS.GeometryUtility" locator="GWMWFS.GeometryUtility"><ExceptionText>Unsupported geometry type.</ExceptionText></Exception></ExceptionReport>
```

According to [this](http://www.opengeospatial.org/resource/products/details/?pid=786) GeoMedia WebMap Professional 6.1 is WFS 1.1.0 compliant.  And according to [this](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/1427) my query looks valid.

So does this error suggest that WebMap is unable to do a BBOX query against a polygon?  Should the query be formed differently?  Links to WebMap WFS 1.1.0 filter examples would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the <Box> element..it is enough to have only the <Envelope> element:

```
http://usgvdcalix2/WFS/Request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=500&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><BBOX><PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName><Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><lowerCorner>43.944567565918 -72.742129821777</lowerCorner><upperCorner>44.148836975098 -72.545288391113</upperCorner></Envelope></BBOX></Filter>&TYPENAME=Counties
```

Also, for WFS 1.1.0 ESPG:4326 is correctly interpreted as lat/lon not lon/lat so reverse those values.

As far as other examples go, here are some non-spatial examples provided by Intergraph support:

```
http://somehost/request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=SwPipe&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="!" escapeChar="\"><PropertyName>Construction</PropertyName><Literal>ABS</Literal></PropertyIsLike></Filter>

http://somehost/request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=GND1_NAME_INFORMATION&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&FILTER=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="!" escapeChar="\"><PropertyName>FEATURE_COUNTRY_CD</PropertyName><Literal>RS</Literal></PropertyIsLike></Filter>

http://somehost/request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=GND1_NAME_INFORMATION&Filter=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="_" escapeChar="\"><PropertyName>NAME_READING_ORDER</PropertyName><Literal>Philadelphia*</Literal></PropertyIsLike></Filter>

http://somehost/Request.aspx?VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=gmgml:States&SRSName=EPSG:4326&Filter=<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><And><PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>Population</PropertyName><Literal>1000000</Literal></PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>SqMiles</PropertyName><Literal>10000</Literal></PropertyIsGreaterThan></And></Filter>
```

Comment: Interesting note I ran across in GeoMedia documentation.  It states, "if the WMS version is 1.3.0, the authority is EPSG, and the EPSG code range is >=4000 and <5000, the default is Y,X, else, the default is X,Y."

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what geometry types the WFS server supports. Do a GetCapabilities request and check `//ogc:GeometryOperands`, which provides a list of supported geometry types.

**Update**: as well, make sure your WFS GetFeature request has proper referencing to namespaces, and of geometry types.

```
http://host/path?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=$typename&filter=<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><ogc:BBOX><ogc:PropertyName>$geometry_name</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>47 -5</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>55 20</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></ogc:BBOX></ogc:Filter>
```

Where $typename is the name of the FeatureType you wish to query, and $geometry_name is the name of the geometry of the FeatureType.

Comment: Thank you.  I did this using http://usgvdcalix2/WFS/Request.aspx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0 and it reports the following capabilities:
gml:Envelope, gml:Point, gml:LineString, gml:Polygon, gml:Arc, gml:Circle

It also report the following Spatial Ops:

<ogc:SpatialOperators>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="BBOX"/>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="Disjoint"/>
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="Intersects"/>
<!-- <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Contains"/> -->
<ogc:SpatialOperator name="Within"/>
</ogc:SpatialOperators>